# Independent hardware-based encryption tool, used with non-cooperative system and drive

Tags: encryption, usb-storage, embedded, dongle

I have a small embedded system that supports FAT32. It does not have any encryption options for the files that it saves to an external USB-connected disk. Modifying the source to support encryption is not an option.

Are there any external drives, or anything that can be used to encrypt the files once they land on the disk? Something that does not require the cooperation of the embedded system?

I realize that this is a bit far fetched, but you never know!

Comment: Do you want a drive that can do encryption for you, or do you want a piece of software?

Comment: drive that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2380385,00.asp), [that](http://www.macworld.com/article/142370/2009/08/padlock.html), and perhaps also [over there](http://www.hdd.no/)

disclaimer: i am not affiliated with these makers and certainly did not hvae enough money to try these expensive solutions...

also note that a non-cooperative system is different from a potential hostile system which require something more sophisticated that these..